# How to calculate Sum of values per Quarters based on task start date and end date in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have an Activity table with Type,StartDate,EndDate and Amount.
I want to calculate the sum of amounts grouped by Type for all the quarters using start date and enddates.

For example, if I have StartDate and EndDate falls between Jan to Mar then sum of all the records' amounts
related to that quarter should be calculated.

And I want to do the same for the remaining records.

```
CREATE TABLE activity
(id int(11)
,Type varchar(10)
,StartDate date
,EndDate date
,Amount int(11)
);
                                                                                         
INSERT INTO activity VALUES
(1,'Type1','2021-01-15','2021-02-25',10000),
(2,'Type1','2021-01-25','2021-02-25',10000),
(3,'Type2','2021-08-05','2021-09-25',15000),
(4,'Type3','2021-10-15','2021-12-25',5000);
```

This is the expected output.

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

```
Type        T1      T2      T3      T4
Type1       20000   0       0       0
Type2       0       0       15000   0
Type3       0       0       0       5000


T1,T2,T3,T4 are quarters of Year

T1 -> Jan TO Mar
T2 -> April TO June
T3 -> July TO September
T4 -> October TO December
```

I have tried a query. I have given that query in the online editor.

[This is the Online editor link with sample data.](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7ogCb6Zts7kbgjt6mhSkq3/0)

Is there anything I'm missing in my query to fetch the correct response?

Comment: Your output doesn't make sense, because the 2000 from the 2nd quarter is actually spead out across T2 and T3.  Please edit your question with the output you really want here.

Comment: It's nice that date ranges never straddle quarters

Comment: Hey, @TimBiegeleisen , I've updated the expected result. Could you please look into that and suggest me where am doing wrong and how to achieve the solution

Comment: @Aravind I'm not going to edit my answer, but [here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c78eb8051ddb3172d339686a7d5becf0) using my current query along with updated data from above.

Comment: That's fine, @TimBiegeleisen . But how would I perform ```WITH Activity``` if I have multiple records?

Comment: @Aravind `WITH Activity (...)` is a common table expression, I am using this in lieu of going to the trouble of defining and populating a formal table.  If your scope already has an `Activity` table, then just delete `WITH Activity (...)` ; you don't need it.

Comment: Thanks, @TimBiegeleisen . Now I understood. Thanks for explaining

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may handle this requirement with the help of a calendar table, which in this case maintains the date ranges for each quarter:

```
SELECT
    a.Type,
    SUM(CASE WHEN quarter = 'T1' THEN a.Amount ELSE 0 END) AS T1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN quarter = 'T2' THEN a.Amount ELSE 0 END) AS T2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN quarter = 'T3' THEN a.Amount ELSE 0 END) AS T3,
    SUM(CASE WHEN quarter = 'T4' THEN a.Amount ELSE 0 END) AS T4
FROM Activity a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT 'T1' AS quarter, '2021-01-01' AS QuarterStart, '2021-04-01' AS QuarterEnd UNION ALL
    SELECT 'T2', '2021-04-01', '2021-07-01' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'T3', '2021-07-01', '2021-10-01' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'T4', '2021-10-01', '2022-01-01'
) q
    ON a.StartDate < q.QuarterEnd AND a.EndDate >= q.QuarterStart
GROUP BY
    a.Type;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Note that I changed your sample data, because the current Type 2 data actually spans both the 2nd and 3rd quarters, and you did not make it clear how the accounting should work in this case.  So, I changed the end date for that data to 2020-06-30 to ensure that it only falls in the 2nd quarter.

Comment: Note: The subquery I aliased as `q` above should probably exist as a separate table.  Call it `quarters` or something like that.  It can also contain quarters from more than 1 year.

Comment: Thank you and ya I did the same. I created a view for the quarter and joined in the main query. It worked as expected